# Using Android NDK in Win 7 64 bit with Eclipse Juno, get "directory name is invalid"

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk

I'm on Windows 7 Pro 64 bit (pity me) trying to run Eclipse Juno to compile an Android app using the NDK (both the ADT and the NDK have both just been downloaded).

I had found a page discussing installing Cygwin beforehand, and so installed that.

Then I installed the ADT, and the NDK. My environment variables are below.

I have a relatively complex application.  It relies on 15-20 subprojects.  6 of these are NDK-based projects.

If I cd to the root of one of these projects, I can do an ndk-build just fine.  In fact, Eclipse can also build these projects just fine.

The problem is that the main project that I'm trying to compile (though it has no JNI code at all (not even a jni directory)), the error message for the main project is:

Cannot run program "I:\programming\Android\android-ndk-r10\ndk-build.cmd": The directory name is invalid.

Adding an empty jni directory doesn't make a difference.

The path does exist, as I can CD into it and run ndk-build successfully from the command line.

So how could I find out the path that's causing the problem?

Is this an error of using the wrong file path separator?  How can I find out?

Any input appreciated.

---

```
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
AMDAPPSDKROOT=C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\2.9\
ANDROID_HOME=I:\programming\Android\android-sdk
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=I:\programming\Android\android-ndk-r10
ANT_HOME=C:\utils\apache-ant
APPDATA=C:\Users\kcorey\AppData\Roaming
asl.log=Destination=file
AVR32_HOME=i:\WinAVR-20100110
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=KCOREY-PC
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
GS_PROG=i:\program files\gs\gs9.02\bin\gswin64.exe
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\kcorey
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\kcorey\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\KCOREY-PC
NDKROOT=I:\programming\Android\android-ndk-r10
NDK_ROOT=I:\programming\Android\android-ndk-r10\
NDK_WIN_HOST=windows-x86_64
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
OPENSSL_CONF=i:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\kcorey\AMD APP SDK\2.9\bin\x86_64;C:\Users\kcorey\AMD APP SDK\2
.9\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\2.9\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\2.9\bin\x86;i:\WinAVR-20100110\bin;i
:\WinAVR-20100110\utils\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Common
 Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;i:\Program Files (x86)\Common
 Files\GTK\2.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;i:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86
)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;I:\Program Files\nodejs\;c:\utils;I:\programming\A
ndroid\android-sdk\tools;I:\programming\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;I:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Fil
es\TortoiseGit\bin;I:\programming\Android\android-ndk-r10;i:\cygwin64\bin;c:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsof
t Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;i:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\GTK\2.0\bin;C:\Prog
ram Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;i:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\P
rogram Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;I:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;i:\Ruby192\bin;i:\Program Files (
x86)\Nmap;i:\programming\android\android-sdk;I:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.7.4-Q16;c:\utils;I:\programming\Android\android-sdk\plat
form-tools;C:\Users\kcorey\AppData\Roaming\npm;c:\utils;c:\utils\apache-ant\bin;i:\cygwin64\bin
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.RB;.RBW
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=2a07
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
S3E_DIR=i:\Marmalade\6.2\s3e
SESSIONNAME=Console
SSH_AGENT_PID=27840
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-ckgfv25228/agent.25228
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
TEMP=C:\Users\kcorey\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\kcorey\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=kcorey-PC
USERNAME=kcorey
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\kcorey
VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=I:\Program Files\VirtualBox\
VS100COMNTOOLS=i:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
windir=C:\Windows
```

Comment: This may or may not be related. It appears you are missing `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`. According to David Turner on the NDK Mailing List, both `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` need to be set because other tools depend on those values (see [Recommended NDK Directory?](http://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/qZjhOaynHXc/2ux2ZZdxy2MJ)). Also, ensure you are *not* using Long File Names on Windows (i.e., filenames with spaces in them). Finally, where is your `I:` drive? Is it local or remote?

Comment: Hi jww, thanks for writing!  As it happens there were two issues: no ANDROID_SDK_ROOT, which is bad enough, but ANDROID_HOME pointed to a old version of ADT which was in another place.

So, what I did was to set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to the home location, and then clean and build.

Sadly, this didn’t fix the issue…same problem.

Thanks anyway,

-Ken